# Fall back font is displayed till loading an icon in material design

Tags: angular, material-design

I am using material design. When in a slow network the fall back text " keyboard_arrow_down " is shown in my website in place of toggle icon. I need to prevent showing this fall back text. 
is there any way which prevents the fall back text from displaying.

Comment: can you share code

Comment: <mdl-select id="Mdlselect" >                                    
                                    <mdl-option  tabindex="4" value="Allobjects">All objects</mdl-option>
                                    <mdl-option *ngFor="let item of items" [value]="item.id">{{item.shortName}}</mdl-option>
                                </mdl-select>

Comment: pass an empty string on the place of  " keyboard_arrow_down " (ie: " ")

Answer (score 2):

This is the default behaviour for material design. You cannot fix this issue using any workaround. This needs to be fixed from the material design part. You can check this by reducing your band width in browser settings and loading the below samples https://material-components.github.io/material-components-web-catalog/#/component/button

Comment: this answer has a lucky id:  51513131  ;)

Answer (score 1):

If your fetching items using async , you can use conditional classes with ngClass

**Example:**

ng-class="'label-success': item != null, 'label-warning': item == null"

if item object exist 'label-success' class will be added otherwise 'label-warning' class, and work on those classes according to your needs.